# Problema con instalación de rubyonrails en windows7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estoy intentando instalar rubyonrails en una maquina con win7 y me sale este error
al utilizar el comando "gem rails install":
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed

¿Alguien que me pueda dar una mano?

Comment: Como estas haciendo la instalación? para windows puedes usar [Rails Installer](http://railsinstaller.org/en)

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo instalar sobre linux rails con windows tiene muchos problemas con los certificados ssl, widows de por si tienen muchos permisos, cuando comence fue un dolor de cabeza y cuando me cambie a linux no tuve ni 1 solo problema es la mejor opción animo que el bash de windows es malisimo unix es amoroso en todo sentido para codear !